# Change image on hover and click, on mouseover keep the image from the click

Tags: jquery, image, click, hover, mouseout

I'm a jQuery noob so maybe you can help me with my code. I have an image. I want that on hover the image changes, and when i click on it another (3th) image comes in and when i go mouseout I want to keep the 3th image (if clicked). Every image must faded in.

Maybe you can help me? Until now I only have the hover worked and the on click, but without fadein / fadeout and keeping the click image when mouseout.

Here's my code but I think you can get write better code.

```
$("img#hovertom").hover(
  function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_hover.png");
  }, 
  function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom.png");
  }
);

$("img#hoverdaniel").hover(
  function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_hover.png");
  }, 
  function () {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel.png");
  }
);
```

In the html I only have the image with ID hovertom.

Comment: Create a demo using [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a similar website with an example of how it's currently working and you'll probably get faster answers.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do it in jQuery, it's much simpler to do in the tag or CSS [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Farmh/), but that changes on hover later. You can do it [like this](http://jsbin.com/arazaf/2/edit) with straight javascript and CSS and it will work like you want it to

But since you want it in jQuery, you can do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Farmh/3/)

```
var clicked = false;
$("#hovertom").mouseleave(function () {
    if(!clicked)
        $(this).attr("src", "http://www.so-gnar.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/TOMS-SHOES.jpg");
});
$("#hovertom").mouseenter(
  function () {
      if(!clicked)
        $(this).attr("src", "http://images.toms.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/side/900x640/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/-/w-red-canvas-classics-s-su12.jpg");
});
$("#hovertom").click(
  function () {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://images.toms.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/side/900x640/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/-/w-ash-canvas-classics-s-su12_1.jpg");
    clicked = true;
});
```

And just repeat it switching out the ID and srcs for the second one or apply it to a class or simply the 'img' tag instead